# How did the Linux operating system display and update progress bars?

Tags: linux, terminal, escaping, ansi-escape

For instance, when you pull images from Docker Hub, progress bars (downloading, extracting) in terminal show the progress and **are refreshed** in accordance with the progress:

```
9b5a7fa51869: Downloading [==============>                                    ]  8.485MB/29.15MB
9b5a7fa51869: Pull complete
9a72a43d6e84: Extracting [=>                                                 ]  2.785MB/89.96MB
```

I think if you want to print something to the command line, you put content to some `channel` or stdout, and it will **append to the stream, not update**.

I looked up on Internet but I was unable to get any helpful information.

Can you explain how it worked?

Comment: Look at pseudo-graphic libraries like ncurses to be able to do character oriented pseudo-graphic display on terminals. You can also have a look at escape sequences to move the cursor, set colors... (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the so-called escape sequences, it is possible to send character sequences which will be interpreted by the terminal as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Here is for example, a simple shell script which displays a rule in reverse video and moves the cursor 1 step backward on the rule every seconds:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

[ $# -ne 1 ] && echo "Usage: `basename $0` chrono_value" >&2 && exit 1

# Reverse video (ESC [ 7 m)
echo -ne "\033[7m"

chrono=$1

# Display of the rule
i=$1
while [ $i -gt 0 ]
do
    echo -n "="
    i=`expr $i - 1`
done

# Move the cursor backward on the rule
while [ $chrono -gt 0 ]
do
    sleep 1
    chrono=`expr $chrono - 1`
    # Move the cursor backward (ESC [ 1 D)
    echo -ne "\033[1D"
    
done

# Reverse video (ESC [ 7 m)
echo -ne "\033[7m"

echo
```

Example of execution:

[image]

The below script increases the length of an arrow every seconds:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

[ $# -ne 1 ] && echo "Usage: `basename $0` arrow_length" >&2 && exit 1

length=$1

while [ $length -gt 0 ]
do
  # Move the cursor one step backward to overwrite the preceding arrow's end
  echo -ne "\033[1D=>"
  sleep 1
  length=`expr $length - 1`
done

echo
```

Example of execution:

[image]